# SQL SP - Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am getting an error message when executing this stored procedure, the message is:

Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure stpr_SP1, Line 42
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure stpr_SP1, Line 55
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Can anyone help with this as I am stuck! Below is the code, thanks.

```
SELECT CASE @GroupType WHEN 'Store' THEN
        (select top 100 percent dbo.Table1.Field1 
        ,dbo.Table1.Location
        ,count(dbo.Table1.URN) AS [OrderCount]
        ,convert(numeric(18,2),avg(dbo.Table1.Value)) AS [ValueAvg]
FROM dbo.Table1
GROUP BY dbo.Table1.Field1
        ,dbo.Table1.Location
ORDER BY dbo.Table1.Field1 ASC
        ,dbo.Table1.Location ASC)

WHEN 'Customer' THEN
        (select top 100 percent dbo.Table1.Field1
        ,dbo.Table1.InvoiceCode
        ,dbo.Table1.Location
        ,count(dbo.Table1.URN) AS [OrderCount]
        ,convert(numeric(18,2),avg(dbo.Table1.Value)) AS [ValueAvg]
FROM dbo.Table1
GROUP BY dbo.Table1.Field1
        ,dbo.Table1.InvoiceCode
        ,dbo.Table1.Location
ORDER BY dbo.Table1.Field1 ASC
        ,dbo.Table1.InvoiceCode ASC
        ,dbo.Table1.Location ASC)
END
```

Comment: A scalar subquery can only return one column.  Your code just won't work.  Perhaps you just want `if` rather than `select case`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff And 1 row

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you want `IF` and not `SELECT CASE`:

```
IF @GroupType = 'Store'
BEGIN
    select top 100 percent dbo.Table1.Field1, . . .
END;
IF @GroupType = 'Customer' 
BEGIN
    select top 100 percent dbo.Table1.Field1, . . .
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

A `CASE` in SQL is an *expression*, meaning that it returns a value (a single one). What you want is an `IF`:

```
IF @GroupType = 'Store'
BEGIN
    SELECT  t.Field1,
            t.Location,
            COUNT(t.URN) AS [OrderCount],
            CONVERT(numeric(18,2),AVG(t.Value)) AS [ValueAvg]
    FROM dbo.Table1 t
    GROUP BY t.Field1,
             t.Location
    ORDER BY t.Field1 ASC,
             t.Location ASC
END
IF @GroupType = 'Customer'
BEGIN
    SELECT  t.Field1,
            t.InvoiceCode,
            t.Location,
            COUNT(t.URN) AS [OrderCount],
            CONVERT(numeric(18,2),AVG(t.Value)) AS [ValueAvg]
    FROM dbo.Table1 t
    GROUP BY t.Field1,
             t.InvoiceCode,
             t.Location
    ORDER BY t.Field1 ASC,
             t.InvoiceCode,
             t.Location ASC
END
```